# Concurrency and Selenium - Multiprocessing vs Multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, selenium, concurrency

I have a script that uses a lot of headless Selenium automation and looped HTTP requests. It's very important that I implement a threading/worker queue for this script. I've done that.

My question is: Should I be using multi-thread or multi-process? Thread or ProcessPool? I know that:

*"If your program spends more time waiting on file reads or network requests or any type of I/O task, then it is an I/O bottleneck and you should be looking at using threads to speed it up."*

and...

*"If your program spends more time in CPU based tasks over large datasets then it is a CPU bottleneck. In this scenario you may be better off using multiple processes in order to speed up your program. I say may as it’s possible that a single-threaded Python program may be faster for CPU bound problems, it can depend on unknown factors such as the size of the problem set and so on."*

Which is the case when it comes to Selenium? Am I right to think that all CPU-bound tasks related to Selenium will be executed separately via the web driver or would my script benefit from multiple processes?

Or to be more concise: When I thread Selenium in my script, is the web driver limited to 1 CPU core, the same core the script threads are running on?

Comment: I found some other SO posts (in different languages) and in blogs (Java) that explained trying to speed up testing with multi-threading, with each thread controlling a separate webdriver. Have you confirmed it is the python process, and not the driver rendering engine that is your bottleneck?

Comment: Have not. I already have everything implemented using thread pool. I was reading about process pool and wondering if I should optimize with it. By @Sraw answer I should not.

Comment: OK, threading had the right 'feel' to me, with a webdriver per thread but I'm not really sure how to explain why. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web driver is just a driver, a driver cannot drive a car without a car.

For example when you use `ChromeDriver` to communicate with browser, you are launching Chrome. And `ChromeDriver` itself does no calculation but Chrome does.

So to clarify, webdriver is a tool to manipulate browser but itself is not a browser.

Based on this, definitely you should choose thread pool instead of process pool as it is surely an I/O bound problem in your python script.